# The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the collection

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to send a request to the Cosmos DB API in Azure, using PowerShell, but I keep getting the following error back from the service:

"The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the collection."

This is also the case when I use the x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey header, and happens whether I attempt a GET (read) request, or try to POST/PUT (create/update) a document.  If I try to send a value of an empty array, or an array with a single empty string, or the enumeration "None", I get an error message that "partition key None is invalid" (or whatever value I gave).

However, my collection was created before partition keys were required, so my collection originally did not have partition keys.  After migrating my database, the collection Settings tab shows a "Partition key" value of `/_partitionKey`, with Large partition key being enabled.  There is also a note that the container is non-hierarchically partitioned.  BUT, none of my documents have a property "_partitionKey", and no value for one.

How can I work with the Cosmos API using native PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an enormous amount of searching and trial/error, I was finally able to get something to work.  Feel free to use this for your own PowerShell needs.

## Authenticate

First, you'll need to authenticate.  You can hardcode the access key, or you can dynamically retrieve it using the following command.

```
$keys = Invoke-AzResourceAction -Action "listkeys" `
    -ResourceType "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts" `
    -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
    -Name $cosmosAccountName `
    -ApiVersion "2015-04-08" `
    -Force

$keys.primaryMasterKey            # Use this one for writing.
$keys.primaryReadonlyMasterKey    # Use this one for reading.
```

You'll need to take that key, and generate an authentication header.  But to do that, you need to know what URL you are going to be making a request against, and what verb (e.g. POST, PUT, etc.).

If you are executing a query, your **ResourceLink** would be the collection documents (e.g. `dbs/myDatabase/colls/myCollection/docs`).  If you are creating or changing a document, your **ResourceLink** would be a specific document (e.g. `dbs/myDatabase/colls/myCollection/docs/myDocGUID`).  In either of these examples, your **ResourceType** would be `docs`.

```
# Credit from this URL: https://sql-articles.com/articles/azure/cosmos-db/provisioning-azure-cosmos-db-using-powershell/

function Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([string])]
    Param (
        # The HTTP verb going to be used with this authorization signature.  Can choose from 'DELETE', 'GET', 'PATCH', 'POST', or 'PUT'.
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet("DELETE", "GET", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT")]
        [string] $Verb,

        # The access key to use for authentication to the target.
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Key,

        # Optional Parameter.  The link of the resource we are requesting access to (e.g. dbs/myDatabase/colls/myCollection/docs/myDocID).
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $ResourceLink = [string]::Empty,

        # Optional Parameter.  The type of resource we are requesting access to (e.g. docs).
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $ResourceType = [string]::Empty,

        # Optional Parameter.  The date and time to attach to this signature.  Default value is right now, UTC.
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $DateTime = ([DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("r")),

        # Optional Parameter.  The type of key the Key value represents.  Default value is 'master'.
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $KeyType = "master",

        # Optional Parameter.  The algorithm version that was used to generate the key (e.g. 1.0).  Default value is '1.0'.
        [Parameter()]
        [string] $TokenVersion = "1.0"
    )

    Process {
        $hmacSha256 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
        $hmacSha256.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Key)
        if ($ResourceLink -eq $ResourceType) {
            $ResourceLink = [string]::Empty
        }

        $payload = "$($Verb.ToLowerInvariant())`n$($ResourceType.ToLowerInvariant())`n$ResourceLink`n$($DateTime.ToLowerInvariant())`n`n"
        $hashPayload = $hmacSha256.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payload))
        $signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hashPayload)
        return [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=$KeyType&ver=$TokenVersion&sig=$signature")
    }
}
```

If you declare and then invoke the above function, you'll get the value needed for your `authorization` header.

## Headers

```
$headers = @{
    authorization         = $authSig
    "x-ms-date"           = $dateTime
    "x-ms-version"        = "2020-07-15"
    "x-ms-max-item-count" = 100
}    # Shared headers used by all requests.
```

If you are querying data, you'll need the following headers (in addition to those above):

- `x-ms-documentdb-isquery: true/false`
- `x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition: true/false`
- `x-ms-documentdb-query-parallelizecrosspartitionquery: true/false`
- `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkeyrangeid: #`
  Your content type will be `application/query+json`.  If you don't use partitions, or migrated from a partitionless collection, set `0` as your range ID.  [You can find the range IDs available to you by running a GET on the collection for pkranges.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-partition-key-ranges)

If you are changing data, you'll need the following headers (in addition to shared):

- `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey: []`
  Your content type will be `application/json`.  If you don't use partitions, or migrated from a partitionless collection, set an empty array `[]` as your partition key.  Otherwise, give an array with a single string with your partition key (right now they only support using one at a time).

## Body

If you are querying data, your body will be a JSON body containing the query.  You can also play around with parameters if you need, as a separate JSON property.

```
$body = @{
    query = "select * from C"
}
```

If you are changing data, your body will either be the entire document (when creating or replacing), OR a [patch operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/patch-a-document).

```
$body = @{
    operations = @(
        @{
            op = "replace"
            path = "/myJsonPath"
            value = "blah"
        }
    )
}
```

## Request

Set your TLS to 1.2, just in case.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Finally, send your request.  The content of a successful response will have a `Documents` array property that you can dig through.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method $verb -Uri $url -ContentType $contentType -Headers $headers -Body $body -UseBasicParsing
```

---

It took me FOREVER to figure out the partition key stuff for collections that were created without a partition key, so I thought I would document it here.  If you need more help, or want to dig more, check here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/documents